# Wiener transformation - K-Apriori Algorithm

Tags: data-transformation, apriori

Wiener transformation is used to transform a binary data to a real data? How it works? Is there a R package that implements this transformation?

I have been searching about Market Basket Analysis and I have found that one algorithm it uses in order to get some rules, which are the goals of this analysis, is an algorithm named "K-Apriori Algorithm". This research: "**Market Basket Analysis for a Supermarket based on Frequent**" by Loraine Charlet Annie M.C.1 and Ashok Kumar, says about K-apriori algorithm: "K-Apriori is based on the Apriori property and the Association rule generation procedure of the Apriori algorithm. Initially, **the binary data is transformed into real
domain using linear Wiener transformation**. The Wiener transformed data is partitioned using the multi-pass Kmeans algorithm. Then the Apriori procedure is executed for the K clusters in which the sets of items which are greater than minimum support (min_sup) are found
iteratively" . But I would like more information about the Wiener transformation which is mentioned there, how it works? and if there is an R package that implements it.

Comment: Can you add some context? This is likely to be rather esoteric for most people here.

Comment: Hope it can helps!